# Code Splitting ~ ReferenceError: System is not defined

Tags: reactjs, webpack, react-router

My code hit the error

```
ReferenceError: System is not defined
```

In line

```
<IndexRoute getComponent={(nextState, cb) => System.import('./containers/Home').then(module => cb(null, module))} />
```

How do I define `System`. Is it related to my webpack settings? Here how I put it

```
var path = require('path');
var webpack = require('webpack');
var ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');
var HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
var stylus = require('stylus');

module.exports = {
    debug: true,
    devtool: 'eval',
    entry: {
        "vendor": ["react", "react-router", 'react-dom'],
        "app": ['webpack-dev-server/client?http://localhost:3000', 'webpack/hot/only-dev-server', './app/App.js']
    },
    output: {
        pathinfo: true,
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'public'),
        filename: '[name].js',
        publicPath: 'http://localhost:3000/'
    },
    plugins: [
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            title: 'Welcome!',
            template: './index_template.ejs',
            inject: 'body'
        }),
        new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
        new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
            output: {
                comments: false
            },
            compress: {
                warnings: false
            }
        }),
        new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
          name: 'vendor',
          minChunks: Infinity,
          filename: 'vendor.bundle.js'
        })
    ],
    module: {
        loaders: [
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
                loaders: ['react-hot', 'babel']
            },
            {
                test: /\.styl$/,
                exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
                // loader: 'style!css?resolve url?sourceMap&modules&importLoaders=1&localIdentName=[name]__[local]__[hash:base64:5]!postcss!stylus-loader'
                loader: 'style!css?sourceMap&modules&importLoaders=1&localIdentName=[name]__[local]__[hash:base64:5]!postcss!stylus-loader'
            },
            {
                test: /\.(png|jpg)$/,
                exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
                loader: 'url-loader?name=images/[name].[ext]&limit=8192'
            },
            {
                test: /\.(ttf|otf|eot)$/,
                exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
                loader: 'url-loader?name=fonts/[name].[ext]&limit=8192'
            },
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                loader:  'style!css-loader?modules&importLoaders=1&localIdentName=[name]__[local]___[hash:base64:5]'
            },
            {
                test: /\.scss$/,
                loader:  'style!css-loader?modules&importLoaders=1&localIdentName=[name]__[local]___[hash:base64:5]!postcss!sass?resolve url'
            },
            {
                test: /\.json$/,
                loader: 'json-loader'
            }, 
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                include: path.resolve('node_modules/mapbox-gl-shaders/index.js'),
                loader: 'transform/cacheable?brfs'
            }
        ]
    },
    resolve: {
        root: path.join(__dirname, '..', 'app'),
        alias: {
            'react': path.join(__dirname, 'node_modules', 'react')
        },
        extensions: ['', '.js', '.jsx', '.json', '.css', '.styl', '.png', '.jpg', '.jpeg', '.gif']
    },
    stylus: {
        'resolve url': true
    },
    postcss: function () {
        return [autoprefixer];
    }
};
```

> (Disclaimer: I am new to React-Router and webpack, so this may be
>   obvious to someone with more familiarity)

Comment: Do you use webpack 1 or 2?

Comment: right now still using the stable version (1.3)

Comment: So my answer will be appropriate for you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `webpack` build stack probably doesn't have configured `System.import`. I suppose that you use `webpack 1` and support of `System.import` will be only in `webpack 2`.

You can change your existing code to current popular code splitting solution:

```js
<IndexRoute 
    getComponent={(nextState, cb) => {
        require.ensure([], require => {
            // default import is not supported in CommonJS standard
            cb(null, require('./containers/Home').default) 
        });
    }}
/>
```

Note that you must specify `.default` if you want to use default import in CommonJS standard.

Comment: is there any additional setup for webpack?

Comment: @MuhaiminAbdul No, pure barebones `webpack.config.js` will be fine.

Comment: I have update my question along the webpack settings

Comment: one question for mr @Everettss, why the `huge-app` in example of `react-router` didn't show any example for `IndexRoute`

Comment: @MuhaiminAbdul maybe because it wasn't important for this example.